# How can I find Sobolev generalized derivative of function $f(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

Given following function
$$
f(t) := 
\begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ if } t \in (-\infty ,1]  \\ 
 2x -2& \text{ if } t \in (1, 2]  \\ 
 2& \text{ if } t \in (2, 3)  \\ 
 8 - 2x& \text{ if } t \in (3, 4]  \\ 
 0 & \text{ if } t \in (4, \infty)
\end{cases}
$$
How can I find Sobolev generalized derivative of function $f(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $f$ is continuous and piecewise continuously differentiable (say on the intervals $(-\infty,t_1],[t_1,t_2],\dots,[t_{n-1},t_n],[t_n,\infty)$), then
$$
g(t)=\begin{cases}f'(t)&\text{if }t\neq t_k\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
is a weak derivative of $f$. This can be easily seen by splitting up the integral in the definition of weak derivatives and integrating by parts in each of the pieces. I leave it up to you to apply this result to the function at hand.